# Nyquist rate determination and oversampling

Tags: sampling, nyquist

I'm new to this. I'm using ShannonGui to generate a sine wave with a $1\textrm{ Hz}$ signal frequency.

From what I can tell to determine the Nyquist rate I need to double the highest frequency, since it's a constant $1\textrm{ Hz}$, I just double it and get a Nyquist rate of $2\textrm{ Hz}$ correct?

Now I also read that the Nyquist rate is the lowest frequency that you can use as a sampling frequency to avoid aliasing, but when I use $2\textrm{ Hz}$ as the sample frequency the reconstructed wave is a straight line at 0. So does this mean the Nyquist rate is wrong or my understanding of it is wrong?

Comment: It is because you are sampling zero crossings for you sine wave, keep your wave frequency and sampling frequency and only add a phase to you sine, I mean change your signal from y(t)=sin(2*pi*f*t) to something like y(t)=sin(2*pi*f*t+pi/5). Your sampling is correct, however your reconstruction at sampling in exactly nyquiest rate might be so hard or even impossible.

Answer (score 4):

you actually have to sample at **more** than twice the highest frequency.  if $B$ is the bandwidth or highest frequency and $f_\text{s}$ is the sampling frequency, then to satisfy the Sampling Theorem (for normal baseband sampling):

$$ 2B < f_\text{s} $$

it is **not**

$$ 2B \le f_\text{s} $$

sampling at exactly twice the frequency of a sinusoid is *"critically sampling"* and loses amplitude or phase.  it can't get both.  in your case, it is sampling the sinusoid when it crosses zero.

Comment: Okay, thankyou. How much more than it does it have to be, 2.01 for instance shows a wave at less than half the amplitude of the original.

Comment: well, then your reconstruction mathematics is less than perfect.  2x is not enough, but **theoretically** 2.0001x sampling is sufficient.  but you would need a lotta terms of the $\operatorname{sinc}()$ function to do it.

Comment: and **practically** you need to sample a bit more than 2x.  maybe 2.5x when using a cheap reconstruction filter (and impulse response).

Comment: The closer a sampling rate is to critical, the longer you need to sample to get reliable result.